# Replace a string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to replace a string in a file, the content is as below:

```
Time 20073009:20073030
```

**Please note**: the time stamp after "Time" would be different.

I want to replace the time stamp to some other value.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please show us proper sample Input and proper expected output in code tags.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` to replace the stamp for `foo`:

```
echo 'Time 20073009:20073030' | sed -r 's/[0-9]+:[0-9]+/foo/g'
Time foo
```

The string `[0-9]+:[0-9]+` represents a pattern. It means: *one or more digits, followed by :, followed by one or more digits*.

To replace a file's contents:

```
sed -ri 's/[0-9]+:[0-9]+/foo/g' your_file.txt
```

Careful: the `-i` (*in place*) flag will overwrite the file, and the previous content will be lost.